# Grab next post title in archive page

Tags: posts, loop, query

I am using a custom query on a page to display single posts from a specific category, one post per page. Here is my current query:

```
$results = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'cat' => 6
    ) );
```

Right now I have pagination setup that displays < Previous and Next > links. I want to replace those links with the title of the next and previous. Is this possible to do since technically this does not live under a "Single" post but rather more of an archive inside of a page? I have tried `next_post_link()`, etc. but since I am only retrieving one post per page, this doesn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem terribly efficient but you could just look up the next/prev posts in the loop used to display the post then output the post titles in the nav calls.

```
// loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  // ... post display

  // next & prev post data
  $older = get_previous_post();
  $newer = get_next_post();
endwhile; endif;

// pagination
next_posts_link( $older->post_name );
previous_posts_link( $newer->post_name );
```